# Text on the list combobox is not properly aligned

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

```
<div id="speakerDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
<label id="speakerId" for="speaker">Speaker ID*</label>     
<select id="speaker" name="speaker_r" tab-index="2" class="ui-li-count">
       <option value="">SELECT YOUR SPEAKER ID</option>
        <option value="PH">vd_phani</option>
        <option value="AD">vd_aditya</option>
        <option value="PR">vd_prashant</option>
        <option value="SR">vd_sriram</option>
        <option value="KA">vd_kapil</option>
        <option value="MA">vd_maruthi</option></font>
    </select>
</div>
```

the default value is also including the all options on list combobox initially. How to solve this problem???

On the button is displaying the string "SELECT YOUR SPEAKER ID" twice and then displays all options on button in continuation. How??

Comment: What's the random <font> tag doing?  Remove that for a start.

Comment: Make sure there isnt any stupid spaces in your code, and all spaces are tabs. Maybe post the "before" genereted code :)

Comment: @Marco HTML actively ignores any extra spaces, so anything other then 1 consecutive space will be ignored. Also, I prefer to use spaces over tabs as some source code viewers might see it as an ugly character and not a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/forms/selects/index.html

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/wHDSw/3/ (second part you need to test locally)